# How can i start with learning Jquery

Tags: jquery

what is the best blog to start with the Jquery.
Let me know if any video tutorials blogs

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page ?

Comment: The best way should actualy be taking a look at their documentation since they usualy have nice examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer Looks silly but in internet we can find any number of examples for jquery..

use http://www.w3schools.com where it xplains in details.

Comment: Not w3schools, please - see http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

Of course, you already need to know some javascript basics...

Answer (score 0):

Official website http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery